# Difference between IobServer and IobServable in c#

Tags: c#, comparison, difference

Can any one explain about the difference between *IObServer* and *IObServable* in c#?

The documentation for both looks very similar. So, I want to know the scenarios where `IObServer<T>` and `IObServable<T>` should be used?

Comment: What in the documentation is not clear. Its crystal clear https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The `IObserver<T>` and `IObservable<T>` interfaces provide a generalized mechanism for push-based notification, also known as the observer design pattern.

> The `IObservable<T>` interface represents the class that sends
>   notifications (**the provider**);
>
> The `IObserver<T>` interface represents the class that receives them
>   (**the observer**).

and T represents the class that provides the notification information.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449(v=vs.110).aspx) is clear by itself:

> The **IObservable** interface represents the class that sends
>   notifications (*the provider*); the **IObserver** interface
>   represents the class that receives them (*the observer*). T represents
>   the class that provides the notification information.

So in other words: `IObservable` is a one who pushes notifications to the channel, `IObserver` the one who ones subscribed, start receiving them.